# Wordpress gallery and post association in database

Tags: database, wordpress, associations, gallery, posts

I see galleries are represented as separate post records with `post_type = 'gallery'` in the database.

How is this record (gallery) associated with a basic post (`type = 'post'`) in the terms of database records?

Answer (score 0):

The post type "gallery" is not a default post type of Wordpress so this must be a custom post type in your case.

Custom post types are also stored in the wp_posts table.

This link may explain more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

I hope this answers your question.  If you need more clarification, please be specific.